# C# DateTime.ParseExact with backslashes in format

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got some sub directories that are named with dates like so:

```
C:\SomeDirectory\201309\01
C:\SomeDirectory\201309\02
C:\SomeDirectory\201309\03
C:\SomeDirectory\201309\04
C:\SomeDirectory\201309\05
```

etc.

What I'm trying to do is get the directory listing and then use Linq to limit my results based on a date range.

I've got it working like so:

```
string path = @"C:\SomeDirectory";
DateTime f = new DateTime(2013, 9, 1);
DateTime t = new DateTime(2013, 9, 3);
DateTime dt;
var dirs =
    Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(d => DateTime.TryParseExact(
                 d.Substring(Math.Max(0, d.Length - 9)).Replace("\\", null),
                 "yyyyMMdd",
                 CultureInfo.Invarient,
                 DateTimeStyles.None,
                 out dt)
                 && f <= dt
                 && dt <= t);
```

I would, however, like to change the TryParseExact portion so that I don't have to replace the backslash - like so:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    d.Substring(Math.Max(0, d.Length - 9)),
    @"yyyyMM\dd",
    CultureInfo.Invarient,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt)
```

But, it seems TryParseExact does not like that format.  I was thinking this may have something to do with the CultureInfo - but I was unable to track down a possible solution to help me with the backslash.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a double backslash? Backslash is a special character that `DateTime` formatting uses I believe More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: You could also try using the char value of backslash (find it in the ASCII table)

Comment: Why don't you search only in the single directory below `SomeDirectory`? Or you could first check if: `Where(d=>d.Length==6 && d.All(Char.IsDigit))`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth that was the correct solution - MarcinJuraszek pointed it out in the answers below as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Its possible that my date span could go across multiple months and I would want those results as well.  I should have put that possibility into my example above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN `\` is an escape character. So in `@"yyyyMM\dd"` it removed special meaning from first `d`. You should escape the `\` instead:

> To include a backslash in a result string, you must escape it with another backslash (`\\`).

So try following:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    d.Substring(Math.Max(0, d.Length - 9)),
    @"yyyyMM\\dd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt)
```

Comment: I actually just figured it out by chance - thinking that maybe I had to escape it - and did your exact suggestion.  I will mark it as the answer shortly.  Thank you   :)